# Use IOptionsSnapshot in Startup.ConfigureServices()

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to be able to reload my Swagger configuration without redeploying my service.

So I'm trying to use an `IOptionsSnapshot` directly in the `Startup.ConfigureServices()` method :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<SwaggerSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("BaseTemplate:Swagger"));

    var swaggerSettings = new IOptionsSnapshot<SwaggerSettings>(); //get an instance

    //Configure Swagger
}
```

I guess that the `Startup.ConfigureServices()` is called only once when the application is starting ?

Is there any workaround to use and reload a `IOptionsSnapshot` in the the `Startup.ConfigureServices()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Startup.ConfigureServices() is called only once when the application is starting.

> Is there any workaround to use and reload a IOptionsSnapshot in the
> the Startup.ConfigureServices() ?

Do you mean you want to create the service instance each time they're requested from the service container or once per client request (connection)? If that is the case, you could try to use `AddTransient` method or `AddScoped` method to register the service. Code like this:

```
services.AddScoped<IMyDependency, MyDependency>();
```

More detailed information, see:

**Transient**

*Transient lifetime services are created each time they're requested from the service container. This lifetime works best for lightweight, stateless services. Register transient services with AddTransient.
In apps that process requests, transient services are disposed at the end of the request.*

**Scoped**

*For web applications, a scoped lifetime indicates that services are created once per client request (connection). Register scoped services with AddScoped.
In apps that process requests, scoped services are disposed at the end of the request.*

Reference: [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and [Service lifetimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#service-lifetimes).